# Spring integration Java DSL service actuator (.handle) should use bean

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration app with Java DSL config bootstrapped using `IntegrationFlow` builder pattern. I need to use a `.handle()` method, and I do not want to have a lambda function there, like most of the examples of the web do. Instead, I would like to delegate this to a separate bean (service). How can I implement it?

One example below that I found employs inner class, but I need to use autowired Spring bean that has dependencies on other beans, so inner class is not an option for me. What is the best approach for me to go for?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow icedFlow() {                                    
  return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.queue("iced", 10))      
  .handle(new GenericHandler<OrderItem>() {                          

    @Override
    public Object handle(OrderItem payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
      Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
        + " prepared cold drink #" + coldDrinkCounter.incrementAndGet()
        + " for order #" + payload.getOrderNumber() + ": " + payload);
      return payload;                                                
    }

  })
  .channel("output")                                                 
  .get();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, find a new API since version 1.1:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow greetingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("greetingChannel")
                .handle(this.greetingService)
                .get();
    }

}

@Component
public class GreetingService {

   public void greeting(String payload) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + payload);
   }
}
```

https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/spring-integration-java-dsl-1-1-m1-is-available

There is another overload version for that method:

```
public B handle(Object service, String methodName) {
```

See `IntegrationFlowDefinition` JavaDocs for more info.

**EDIT**

The `.handle(this.greetingService::greeting)` style sample:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow lambdasFlow() {
        return flow -> flow
                .handle(this::divideForHalf)
                .handle(this::logMessage);
    }

    public Integer divideForHalf(Integer payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
        return payload / 2;
    }

    public void logMessage(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("My Message: " + message);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Artem, that was very helpful. I wasn't sure about this method `(Object service, String methodName)` though, since it does not allow compile time checking for method name. Is there any chance that we will see something like `.handle(this.greetingService::greeting)` in future? Either way, great work!

Comment: Well, we can do that already now, but it is tied to the specific Functional interface implementation. The `this.greetingService::greeting` should be the method for `MessageHandler` or for `GenericHandler`.

Comment: _The this.greetingService::greeting should be the method for MessageHandler or for GenericHandler_


I was able to find Functional method signature for `.transform(this.greetingService::greeting)`, but not for `.handle(this.greetingService::greeting)`. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Please, find an EDIT to my answer.