# Error message handler is a one way and cannot configure output channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the following configuration, and I used the following style used in [Spring integration Java DSL service actuator (.handle) should use bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405400/spring-integration-java-dsl-service-actuator-handle-should-use-bean)

```
    
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(PollerMetada poller, FileReadingMessageSource source){
   return IntegrationFlows.from(source, e->e.poller(poller)
            .handle(this::mainHandle)
            .channel("somechannel")
            .get();
}

public FileRequest mainHandle(Message<?> message){
       ...
       return request;
    }
```

But I got error my handler is a one-way MessageHandler, how to make it not a one way so I can configure the output channel? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.handle(this::mainHandle)` API. This one fully fits into a `MessageHandler` contract: `void handleMessage(Message<?> message)`.
Where your method is like this `mainHandle(Message<?> message)`. So, the return type of your method is ignored because that method reference mapped to the `MessageHandler` knows nothing about return type - just `void`.

To make it working with the return type you need to use different API:

```
public <P> B handle(GenericHandler<P> handler) {
```

where contract is this:

```
Object handle(P payload, MessageHeaders headers);
```

To match it into your `mainHandle()` contract it has to be used like this:

```
.handle(Message.class, (p, h) -> mainHandle(p))
```

Or you can use method name-based API:

```
.handle(this, "mainHandle")
```